# Python loop with range step multiplied by two

Tags: python, range

Simply put, I have this function in Java:

```
for( int index = 2; index < size*2; index *= 2 ) // 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...
{
  System.out.print(index + " ");
}
```

I want to do the same thing in a Python loop, but I am stuck on how to make the range function work like that. But I am stuck on how to make the step multiply itself by two, since

```
for index in range(2, size*2, *2):
    print(index)
```

I have tried all the variations I can think of:

```
for index in range(2, size*2, index = index * 2):
    print(index)
```

```
for index in range(2, size*2, index * 2):
    print(index)
```

Comment: 1. Why didn't you try simply transforming the index variable? `i = 2**index`? 2. You could also maintain the variable yourself and use a while loop instead.

Comment: `range` doesn't work that way. It always gives you a range with a pre-defined `start`, `stop`, and `step` which must all be integers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop instead:

```py
size = 129
index = 2

while index < size:
    print(index)
    index *= 2
```

Or you can go even further and define a generator to do it more easily:

```py
def powerloop(mn,mx,step):
    while mn < mx:
        yield mn
        mn *= step

for i in powerloop(2, 129, 2):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an equivalent in python for `for i=1; i<x; i++` without having to break down into using a while loop.  That being said, I think you'll find using range can be quite flexible if you use it in conjunction with python's generator comprehensions.

```
for index in (i*2 for i in range(1,size)):
    print(index)
```

I feel like this is somewhat more elegant because you don't need to concern yourself with remembering to have a condition of `i<size*2` since the multiplication is kept separate from iterating over the numbers 1 -> size.

I suggest a generator here since it keeps closest to the spirit of what you wanted to achieve in Java without resorting to a while loop, solutions involving a list comprehension will first create a list of numbers for your entire range and then iterate over that list, which is different in my mind from what you are trying to mimic. I hope this helps!

edit: Docs around generator expressions in case you aren't familiar https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
terms=10
result = list(map(lambda x: 2 ** x, range(terms)))

for i in range(2,terms):
   print(result[i])
```

output

```
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
print(', '.join([str(2**i) for i in range(1, 10)]))
```

Output:

```
2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512
```

Comment: op just want to implement the for loop like java